# which tag for questions about Apple?

Tags: discussion, tags

Lately there are quite few questions about Apple Inc., commonly referred to as Apple.

Which tags should be user? [apple](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/apple), [apple-inc](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/apple-inc), other or no specific tag at all?

There are currently:

- 5 questions tagged [apple](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/apple), all of them concerning Apple Inc.
- 3 questions tagged [apple-inc](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/apple-inc)
- some 4-5 questions concerning Apple Inc. using generic tags like [computers](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/computers) or [mobile-phones](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mobile-phones)
- some 4-5 questions concerning apples using tags like [nutrition](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nutrition)

Comment: It hasn't been Apple Computer Inc. for nearly a decade. It's just Apple Inc.

Answer (score 3):

Creating a [company](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/company) or [corporation](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/corporation) tag and using that may be more useful and it will prevent having a precedent of each company getting their own tag. I don't think we really need to differentiate through tags questions about apple, microsoft, dell, hp, ibm, etc.